# How to abort upload in AWS S3 javascript SDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm new to AWS, and I need to cancel the upload process using JS SDK, and there is a code sample where I have tried to upload an image and cancel the upload process:

```
var test = s3.upload({
                                Key: fileKey,
                                Body: myfile,
                                ACL: 'private'
                            },
                            function (err, data) {
                                if (err) {
                                } else {
                                }
                            });

                           $("#cancel_Button").on("click", function () {
                                s3.abortMultipartUpload(
                                    params = {
                                        Bucket: data.bucket,
                                        Key: data.key,
                                        UploadId: undefined
                                    },
                                    function (err, data) {
                                        if (err)
                                            console.log(err, err.stack);
                                        else
                                            console.log(data);
                                    }
                                )
                            });
```

Comment: And....What is your Question? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Hi, I have uploaded the image, and I have tried to cancel the upload process as I told you but the cancellation process didn't work as expected, so I want know where I gone wrong. thank you

Comment: does it give back something (Error Code, etc) or anything else?

Comment: yaa It gives back that I should set the uploadID param. but I don't know how to get it

Comment: Could it be that you just made a typo: `$("#cancel_Button").onclick("click", function () {`

Comment: no I don't think that because I have checked everything out if there is a typo, but if you like to check it out it the same code as I attached to the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156002/discussion-between-doggo-and-saif).

Comment: "$("#cancel_Button").onclick("click", function () {" that is not the problem because when I call it works very well